# Make Sharepoint search engine show results as users are typing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

Is there a way to have the Search engine display results as users type? For example as users are typing "open" , results are already starting to show, and as user continues "open powerpoint", the results change automatically without users typing enter. As i am fairly new to Sharepoint 2013, i would like to know if there is a web-part or anything that i could do to achieve that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do using the JQuery UI with rest API.The REST API in SharePoint 2013 can easily be integrated using javascript, as the returns can be returned as JSON.

Please see the below blog for the complete script as i cant attach it here.

[Using jQuery UI autocomplete with the REST API to get search results in the search box](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murads/archive/2013/02/20/using-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-the-rest-api-to-get-search-results-in-the-search-box.aspx)

Another example here http://www.techmikael.com/2013/06/extending-existing-search-box-in.html